# Resources on the stationary Schrödinger equation with the soliton potential

Tags: differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, elliptic-functions

I am studying the following Lamé equation in the Jacobi form
\begin{equation}
     -\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2} - \left(2k^2 \operatorname{cn}^{2}\left [x\;|\;k\right ]\right)v = \lambda v,
\end{equation}
where $k\in(0, 1)$ is parameter related to the elliptic modulus of the Jacobi elliptic functions.
In order to better understand this equation I am first taking the soliton limit when $k\rightarrow 1$ to obtain the following differential equation
\begin{equation}
    -\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2} - 2\operatorname{sech}^2{(x)}v = \lambda v,
\end{equation}
for which analytic solutions exist depending on the values of the parameter $\lambda$. For different behaviour of eigenfunction $v$ is observed for $\lambda=-1,$ $\lambda\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,0)$ and $\lambda\geq 0.$ I believe I obtained the correct solutions; however, I am having hard time finding them explicitly in the literature. Does anyone know good resources on the latter equation, or if it is known under a special name? My ultimate goal is to use these solutions in the context of the KdV equation, which is a compatibility condition for the stationary Schrödinger equation
\begin{equation}\label{SE}
   -\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2} - u(x,t) v = \lambda v
\end{equation}

Answer (score 6):

The Schrödinger equation with the $\text{sech}^2$ potential (sometimes called the [Pöschl–Teller potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential)) was first studied by Epstein in 1930 [1]. There is an extensive literature on this exactly solvable case. Two recent references are [2,3]. A special feature of this potential is that it is *reflectionless*, it admits unit transmission at all energies. For that reason it has also found many real-world applications, in particular in photonics.

1. P.S. Epstein, [Reflection of waves in an inhomogeneous absorbing medium](https://www.jstor.org/stable/85754)
   (1930).
2. J. Lekner, [Reflectionless
   eigenstates of the $\text{sech}^2$ potential](http://www.physics.smu.edu/scalise/P6335fa21/notes/Reflectionless_eigenstates.pdf) (2007).
3. C.S. Park, [Transmission time of a particle in the reflectionless sech-squared potential](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960111009340) (2011).

Comment: A further nice pedagogical paper on the reflectionless potentials, solved via supersymmetry operators, is http://www.physics.smu.edu/scalise/P6335fa19/notes/ReflectionlessPotential.pdf